# Is there a way to retrieve data from mysql as soon as a new row is added?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to send notification from one user to the other. I need to know if there is a way to receive the new row as it is added in the database? Something like a firebase "onchildadded()" function. Also is there a better way to send and receive notifications?

Comment: your code did the adding - so you know to do something else afterwards

Comment: if you are using PDO, use PDO::lastInsertId

Comment: please show your code it will be useful to recognize your question more easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be tricky to implement, but the "simple" database method is to use a trigger.  When a row is inserted, you have the opportunity to run other code to do what you want.  This gets tricky, because the row (and perhaps table) is locked while the work is going on.

The "normal" solution to this is polling -- periodically check to see if something new has been added.

For your purposes, these are not the best fit.  You are looking for some sort of message queue.  This is a component where you can write a message to a queue (that a new user has been added) and a receiving process can read the messages in the queue.  I don't think that MySQL has a message queue component built-in.  Undoubtedly, there must be some plug-in somewhere that provides this functionality.  Some databases have this capability built in; for instance, Postgres supports `NOTIFY`.